# How to create a Elastic Search dashboard in Grafana with variable (dropdown to filter data) independent of Time Range Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-analyzers, grafana-variable

I have created a Variable in Grafana 6.6 to provide filter dropdown option to user. I am using Elastic Search datasource. But the dropdown lists are coming filtered by time range .How we can make it independent of time range , in other words I don’t want to apply time range filter for that variable .

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, you can't skip the time range since grafana is specifically designed to display timeseries data. Though, a not so efficient workaround i can suggest is to use a sufficient time range in the dashboard time picker to get all the variables and use relative time range to display data in your panels individually.
As i said, not so efficient.

Do mention if you find an actual solution to the problem.